# How to add Recycler View inside the NestedScrollView which is placed inside a constraint layout, tried to add recycler view but not getting succesful

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to add the `RecyclerView`inside the `NestedScrollView`which is inside a constraint layout,but it not getting add up i.e. `RecyclerView` is not showing up even after adding it up,please help me,I am adding the XML code of it.

what I am doing

1. Adding the `NestedScrollView`inside the constraint layout and adding the `RecyclerView` below the linear layout which is within the `NestedScrollView`.

   ```
    <layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            tools:context=".ui.MainFragment">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_default_back"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scrollview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

                android:fillViewport="true"

                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="45dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_add"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="13dp"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView42"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Received"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="450dp">


                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have two direct views inside the `NestedScrollView`, and There should be a single root layout within the  `NestedScrollView, and then you can nest any other layout within this root.

To fix your problem, you have to wrap the `LinearLayout` & the `RecyclerView` within a root which is arbitrary picked as `LinearLayout`:

```
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"

     tools:context=".ui.MainFragment">

     <include
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         layout="@layout/toolbar_default_back"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

     <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollview"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="200dp"
                 android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                 android:orientation="horizontal"
                 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                 <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/imageView13"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="45dp"
                     app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_add"
                     tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="13dp"
                     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/textView42"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                     android:layout_weight="1"
                     android:text="Received"
                     android:textSize="18sp" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                 android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="450dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

     </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my query,can you pls tell from where we should read more about layouts,I donn't about these property of nestedscroll view before.

Comment: @LavishGarg Glad that could help.. the authentic place is always [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout), but you can look around for medium articles or any authentic android course .. Android now trend for [material design](https://developer.android.com/large-screens) and [jetpack compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose).. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: can you please see this,might you can help me with this issue,I haven't found any such decent tutorial for accessing background location in android 11. Question Link :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824318/how-to-fetch-the-background-location-in-fragment-in-android-11-in-kotlin-none-o

Comment: Hey @LavishGarg I wish I could, but excuses as I didn't dig much on location services, hopefully someone else could help you.